# PowerBI service hover over visual does not show header to allow me to export data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When in powerbi desktop, I can hover over this visual and the header shows up to allow me to export data. When I publish to the service, this no longer happens.

In Options > Report Settings > Export Data I have the option checked to allow end users to export data. Not sure why this is happening. I have many other similar reports that do not behave like this.

In Powerbi Desktop:

[image]

In the Powerbi Service:
[image]

Comment: Is it just this one visual on the report? Have you tried deleting the visual and recreating it?

Comment: The whole report. I actually did try that but it didn’t work.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix without confidential data?